# How can you delete a cookie in an HTTP response?

Tags: http, cookies

What is the preferred way to instruct a browser to delete (or no longer use) an HTTP cookie issued for a given domain in an HTTP response?

(I understand you cannot force the browser to delete the cookie, but there must be a way to indicate that it is no longer valid and should not longer be sent)

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Just set the cookie on exactly the same name, path and domain, but with an `Expires` value in the past. Optionally, set the value to null/empty-string, even if it's just to save the bandwidth, it's otherwise ignored anyway by the average client.

Note that setting on exactly the same path is important. Many starters fail in this by using only the same name and domain and relying on the current request URL for the default path.

From the [RFC 6265 spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265):

> Finally, to remove a cookie, the server returns a Set-Cookie header
> with an expiration date in the past.  The server will be successful
> in removing the cookie only if the Path and the Domain attribute in
> the Set-Cookie header match the values used when the cookie was
> created.

Using `Max-Age=0` will also work with any spec-compliant user agent, but the spec dictates that a server "SHOULD" not do this. Per https://www.rfc-editor.org/errata/eid3430, this is apparently meant to maximise interoperability with non-compliant user agents that only support positive `Max-Age` values.

Comment: According to RFC6265 section 4.1.1, a Max-Age value of 0 is invalid. The user agent MAY delete the cookie if the expiration date is in the past, an the path and domain name match the one in the cookie to delete. Max-Age must not be present. It will be ignored if it has a value 0, but that is an invalid cookie header value.

Comment: @chmike, interestingly [section 5.2.2](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6265#section-5.2.2) does talk about interpreting a value for Max-Age that is less than or equal to 0.

Comment: @Matthijs there is indeed a contradiction. It looks like section 4.1.1 is not valid for Max-Age since, according to section 5.2.2, a value 0 and even negative values are valid. Unfortunately, it is nit explicitly state that it will result in deleting the cookie.

Comment: Well for me when I returned `Set-Cookie: token=deleted; path=/; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT` it worked in Chrome, when I returned `Set-Cookie: token=deleted; path=/; Max-Age=0; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT` Chrome seemed to ignore it. So it seems Chrome shared your initial interpretation of the spec.

Comment: @chmike Though I also thought this was a contradiction, it is not. The point is contemplated in the errata at https://www.rfc-editor.org/errata/eid3430. Apparently the spec authors' intent was to maximise compatibility with existing non-interoperable implementations in the wild by specifying conservative rules for what cookies servers should emit and liberal rules for what cookies user agents must accept. So, a user-agent receiving `Max-Age=0` "MUST" delete the cookie, but a server "SHOULD" never send such a cookie in the first place; the spec-compliant thing to do is to use `expires` instead.

Comment: Balus, I've modified your answer to bring your recommendation in line with the spec. If you approve, feel free to flag the post for the mods to blow away this comment section, since I believe the edit renders the discussion here obsolete.

Comment: This is coming two years later, but I'm glad that the discussion was not blown away as it provides useful context :)