# Multiple login in php

Tags: php, joomla

Hi I'm designing a php login system. I can't figure out though how to prevent multiple logins from the same user account. In other words I'd like to prevent multiple people from logging in on the same account at the same time in different servers.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: you can restrict login sessions to be unique per IP address.

Answer (score 1):

To prevent multiple logins from the same user account:

- Log out any active accounts with the same username when the new user sends a successful login request

OR

- Disable login for the username while the user has been active in the last 15 or so minutes

Comment: If i do like that, iam getting the problem when i clear the cookies.

Comment: @Rakesh You can also make the unique key you assign to their login invalid. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5285940/correct-way-to-delete-cookies-server-side

Comment: @ Harold Seefeld: yeah, its correct only,but when i clear the cookies of my browser,my account will get logged out.after that if i try to login, it is giving an error as "Already log in somewhere else"

Comment: @Rakesh This is what it should follow: `Successful Auth Request` -> `Log out any active sessions` -> `Log in`

Comment: but its not working bro.
after clearing cookies, i need to go to joomla administrator page and then iam logging out

Comment: @Rakesh When you clear your cookies, you clear your identification with the server. You would need to login again.

Comment: yeah i know that,bt if i try logging in, it is showing a message as "already logged in somewhere"

Comment: @Rakesh I'm not sure which code you are using so, try setting it so that your auth request is recieved first before the message appears.

Comment: @  Harold Seefeld: ya thanx bro:)

Comment: actually v are using solr server.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your having a username-pass database or similar to it.
Add a `flag_login` **boolean varible** to the table and Set it to `false` initially.

When a legitimate user tries to login with correct password,
check whether flag_login is false, if yes --> set it to true and **LOGIN**. else login failed.

You can also do a variant like `certain user can login x times` by changing the boolean 
variable to int.