# How to delete cookie

Tags: cookies, go

I wrote a web application that set a cookie and delete it. To clarify to scenario what I mean look at the following code snippet.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
    "net/http"
    "time"
)

func rootHandler(rw http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprintf(rw, "Hello Foo")

}

func setCookieHandler(rw http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    c := &http.Cookie{
        Name:     "storage",
        Value:    "value",
        Path:     "/",
        MaxAge:   0,
        HttpOnly: true,
    }

    http.SetCookie(rw, c)
}

func deleteCookieHandler(rw http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

    c, err := r.Cookie("storage")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }
    c.Name = "Deleted"
    c.Value = "Unuse"
    c.Expires = time.Unix(1414414788, 1414414788000)
}

func readCookieHandler(rw http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

    c, err := r.Cookie("storage")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }
    fmt.Println(c.Expires)
}

func evaluateCookieHandler(rw http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

    c, err := r.Cookie("storage")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }

    if time.Now().After(c.Expires) {
        fmt.Println("Cookie is expired.")
    }
}

func main() {
    mux := mux.NewRouter()
    mux.HandleFunc("/", rootHandler)
    mux.HandleFunc("/cookie", setCookieHandler)
    mux.HandleFunc("/delete", deleteCookieHandler)
    mux.HandleFunc("/read", readCookieHandler)
    mux.HandleFunc("/eval", evaluateCookieHandler)

    http.ListenAndServe(":3000", mux)
}
```

As you can see, when I visit /cookie location, it will be set a cookie as expected. Then when I call /delete, it should change the name, value and expired time from cookie. The expired time is changed, but name and value not.

[image]

What do I want is, to delete the cookie from browser for sign out in a authentication system, when user click sign out button to delete cookie.
I also discover [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5285940/correct-way-to-delete-cookies-server-side) and follow the advice, but does not work as expected.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Cookies are keyed by name, so when you "change" the name, you actually "create" a different cookie, already expired.

Keep the name the same and it should work, but don't forget to take some time one day to read about cookies and how they work.

Comment: First of all, thanks for answer. Do you mean, that I should set only expires field?

Comment: Expires should be enough yes. Setting an empty or "short" value helps cut the payload and avoid leaking data in some cases.

Comment: Do not use the Expires field, use a negative Max-Age instead. Reason: much saner, less traffic, works with unsynchronised clocks. One more thing to pay attention to: Cookies are not only keyed by name but also by path (and domain): Set the explicitly during deletion.

Comment: I change my codes https://gist.github.com/kostonstyle/91d8b8fa87628fa300da. Consider the deleteCookieHandler, I set the max-age negative and when I call /delete path, the max-age stay unchanged, when I look in the browser the cookie. The cookie does not have the max-age in the past. Try the example, and you will see what I mean.

Comment: I figure out, I forgot http.SetCookie(rw, c) at the end from deleteCookieHandler function.

Comment: @Volker IE8 and below don't support Max-Age. http://mrcoles.com/blog/cookies-max-age-vs-expires/

Answer (score 33):

To delete a cookie named "storage", sending set-cookie with the same cookie name.

deleteCookieHandler() should be as follows

```
c := &http.Cookie{
    Name:     "storage",
    Value:    "",
    Path:     "/",
    Expires: time.Unix(0, 0),

    HttpOnly: true,
}

http.SetCookie(rw, c)
```

Answer (score 18):

**MaxAge=0** means no 'Max-Age' attribute specified.

**MaxAge<0** means delete cookie now, equivalently 'Max-Age: 0'

**MaxAge>0** means Max-Age attribute present and given in seconds

```
c := &http.Cookie{
    Name:     "storage",
    Value:    "",
    Path:     "/",
    MaxAge:   -1,
    HttpOnly: true,
}

http.SetCookie(rw, c)
```

Comment: actually according to mozilla: "Number of seconds until the cookie expires. A zero or negative number will expire the cookie immediately. If both Expires and Max-Age are set, Max-Age has precedence." -- see here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie

Comment: @dmaixner You're correct according to the cookie spec, but this answer is correct when dealing with the golang `http.Cookie` struct: https://golang.org/src/net/http/cookie.go

Comment: I can confirm -- this worked for me.