# How do you delete a cookie with Go and http package?

Tags: http, cookies, go

A user has a cookie set when they visit using http.SetCookie like so:

```
expire := time.Now().Add(7 * 24 * time.Hour)
cookie := http.Cookie{
    Name:    "name",
    Value:   "value",
    Expires: expire,
}
http.SetCookie(w, &cookie)
```

If I want to remove this cookie at a later point, what is the correct way to do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to delete cookie](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27671061/how-to-delete-cookie)

Comment: I'd eat a cookie rather than delete it. /omnomnom

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You delete a cookie the same way you set a cookie, but with at time in the past:

```
expire := time.Now().Add(-7 * 24 * time.Hour)
cookie := http.Cookie{
    Name:    "name",
    Value:   "value",
    Expires: expire,
}
http.SetCookie(w, &cookie)
```

Note the `-7`.

You can also set MaxAge to a negative value. Because older versions of IE do not support MaxAge, it's important to always set Expires to a time in the past.

Comment: So best option is doing both MaxAge<0 and Expires in the past in the same cookie?

Answer (score 1):

According to [the doc of cookie.go](https://golang.org/src/net/http/cookie.go), MaxAge<0 means delete cookie now. You can try following codes:

```
cookie := &http.Cookie{
    Name:   cookieName,
    Value:  "",
    Path:   "/",
    MaxAge: -1,
}
http.SetCookie(w, cookie)
```

Comment: Any option to delete all cookies at once ?