# Clear all cookies in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, cookies

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27978868/destroy-cookie-nodejs) shows how to clear a single cookie in NodeJS. Is there a function to clear all cookies without iterating through all of them and clearing them (or expiring them) individually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there isn't. According to RFC for Cookies, a server shouldn't sent multiple responses to clear cookie even.

> If a server sends multiple responses containing Set-Cookie headers
> concurrently to the user agent (e.g., when communicating with the
> user agent over multiple sockets), these responses create a "race
> condition" that can lead to unpredictable behavior.

ALso, you should only be able to send one value for `Set-Cookie`, even in order to unset a cookie.

Read More: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265 [Pg 9]