# Clean session after Fetch() - React native

Tags: react-native, fetch, logout, credentials

How can I clean session after sending a post request using fetch() to login? 
I am using credentials: 'include' , so how do I clean that when I call Log Out ?

I tried researching on this but strangly I couldnt find anyhting!

Here is my fetch() method:

```
login = () => {
    fetch('url', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            Accept: 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Connection': 'Keep-Alive',
        },
        credentials: 'include',
        body: JSON.stringify({
            username: this.state.email,
            password: this.state.password,
        })
    })
```

Comment: Can you post some code? Hard to tell if we don't know how you're storing your session variables

Comment: @Jono  I added code. I just set credentials :'include' to save session.

Comment: Ah got you. This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38558150/cant-delete-cookie-in-express

Comment: @Jono your link has nothing to do with React-Native fetch() cookies.

Comment: Yes but it shows you how to clear your session/cookies from the server when a user logs out.

Comment: @Jono Arent cookies saved somewhere in my computer? I dont want to send a request to clear session i just want to clear it from my pc.

Comment: Do you know the name of the cookies you're trying to clear? If so you can use this library (`remove` function) - https://github.com/reactivestack/cookies/tree/master/packages/universal-cookie#browser-example