# Unable to delete (by setting a short expiry time) the cookie from BROWSER in Express

Tags: javascript, express, cookies, browser, mern

**>What is the issue about:**
I am unable to delete the cookie stored in my browser.

Although, I have tested the cookie deletion functionality in POSTMAN, and it works fine there.

**>Things I have done to delete the cookie:**

i) Send the cookie with **random value** and **past expiry time**

```
const cookieOptions={
            expires: new Date(Date.now()-10*1000), //setting the expiry date to past
            httpOnly:true,
        };
res.cookie("jwt","null",cookieOptions);
```

Here is the logout function for the logout route

```
//authController.js
exports.logout=async(req,res)=>{
    try{
        const cookieOptions={
            expires: new Date(Date.now()-10*1000),
            httpOnly:true,
        };
        console.log("Logging out");
        //res.clearCookie("jwt");                     //Have done this also
        res.cookie("jwt","null",cookieOptions);
        console.log("Deleted");
        res.status(200).json({
            status:"success",
            message:"Cookie has been deleted"
        });
    }catch(err){
        console.log(err);
        res.status(400).json({
            status:"failed",
            message: err.message
        })
    }
}

//userRoutes.js
router.route("/logout").get(authController.logout);
module.exports=router;

//app.js
const userRouter=require("./routes/userRouter")
app.use("/api/v1/users",userRouter);
```

Here is the login function through which user receives a cookie in browser stored as "jwt"

```
//authController.js
exports.login=async(req,res)=>{    
    try{
        const {email,password}=req.body;
        const user=await User.findOne({
            email:email
        }).select("+password");
        if(!user)
            throw `Please enter a valid email or password`;
        const correct=await user.compareNormalPwithHashedP(password,user.password);
        if(!correct) 
            throw `Please provide valid email or password`;   
        console.log(user);
        const token= jwt.sign({id:user._id,name:user.name},process.env.JWT_SECRET,{expiresIn:process.env.JWT_EXPIRES}); 
        const cookieOptions={
            expires:new Date(Date.now()+process.env.COOKIE_EXPIRES*24*60*60*1000),
            httpOnly:true
        }
        res.cookie("jwt",token,cookieOptions);
        res.status(200).json({
            status:"success",
            message:"You have logged in successfully",
            data:{
                user,
            }
        })
    }catch(err){
        console.log(err);
        res.status(400).json({
            status:"failed",
            message: err.message
        })
    }
}
```

ii) tried to **await** the res.cookie   `await res.cookie("jwt","null",cookieOptions);`

iii) tried all sorts of experimentation with the **expires** such as:

```
i)const cookieOptions={
            expires: new Date(0),
            httpOnly:true,
        }
ii)const cookieOptions={
            expires: new Date(Date.now()),
            httpOnly:true,
        }
iii)const cookieOptions={
            expires: new Date(Date.now()+10*1000), //EVEN ADDING 10s EXPIRY TIME
            httpOnly:true,
        }
```

Still, that cookie sits there like a **DUMB KID** in the browser and is not moving at all or even **modifying** itself with the **updated value** and **expiry time**!!!

Here is my Frontend code in React from where its interacting with the Express server:

```
<div className="login-dropdown" onClick={async e=>{
    dispatch({type:"logout"});
    await axios.get("http://localhost:4001/api/v1/users/logout");
    navigation("/");
    window.location.reload();
}}>
   <div style={{display:"flex", marginLeft:"10px",position:"relative",top:"30%"}}>
      <img style={{width:"20px"}} src={logout_logo}/>
      <p style={{marginLeft:"20px"}}>Logout</p>
   </div>    
</div>
```

**Is cookie deletion also not working in POSTMAN??**

**It is working PERFECTLY FINE when I am testing this in POSTMAN.** No worries whatsoever. **However, it is just not working in the browser. I have to manually delete the cookie from the browser for the logout functionality to actually work**

PLEASE help me out as I am almost stuck for 5 hours straight with no solutions coming to the rescue from similar stackoverflow question with answers and in the internet...nothing is resolving this issue.
Please suggest what is going wrong in this piece of program.

Comment: `res.clearCookie('jwt);`  maybe..

Comment: Hey @Keith, thanks buddy but I have also tried with that. Didn't seem to work even on that man

Comment: I am wondering if there are some browser settings that i need to enable or not...although the chance of it very less since I have tried both in Chrome and FireFox.

In both the browsers, the cookie is not getting expired/ modified/ deleted. 
Any luck in this?

Answer (score 0):

Finally the mystery unveils!

So, basically I was just missing out only this test case among all the permutations and combinations..

This naughty little code is hiding in this FrontEnd portion:

```
await axios.get("http://localhost:4001/api/v1/users/logout",{
                                        withCredentials:true
                                    });
```

**I had to include `{withCredentials:true}`** in the **axios.get** function **attached to logout route of backend**

Special thanks to this comment thread
**https://stackoverflow.com/a/57236925/18378336**