# Session destroy in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, session, cookies

In nodejs I'm not able to destroy a session or cookies .. 
Initially I have a login page **'entryForm'** which only takes user credentials.
 If credentials are **authorised** it comes to **'if' part**, id is true and then it redirects to **'mypage'**.,
 Here if I can clear cookies then next time 'entryForm' will come else its getting directed to 'mypage' again!!.

```js
var cookie = require(constants.paths.core + '/helpers/cookie');


module.exports = function(app) {
  app.use(function(req, res, next) {


    console.log(req.headers.referer);

    var cookies = cookie.getCookies(req);
    console.log(cookies)
    var sid = cookies['connect.sid'];
    var Id = cookies['SM_ID'];

    if(Id){ // short id found

      console.log(Id);

      // res.cookie('x-scuid',Id, { maxAge: 900000 });
      call(req,res);
    }
    else {
      req.session.check="try this";
      req.session.back = req.headers.referer;
      res.redirect('/entryForm');//for login page 
      } 

  });
  function call(req,res){
    console.log("id available")
    console.log(req.session.back);
    res.redirect('/mypage');//after authorised
    console.log("after mypage and authorised... i want to destroy sessions");
    res.session.destroy();
    // here im getting error "can't set headers after they are sent"
  }
}
```

How do i clear cookies and destroy session .Please do help thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Destroy cookie NodeJs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27978868/destroy-cookie-nodejs)

Comment: sorry dint get it..can you please code it in answers?!