# Keycloak node.js adapter doesn't invalidate connect.sid session cookie on logout

Tags: node.js, keycloak, express-session, keycloak-nodejs-connect, keycloak-connect

Node.js  [keycloak-nodejs-connect](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-nodejs-connect/tree/v4.3.0) adapter (version 4.3) is used in an application gateway for protecting microservices' endpoints according to [docs](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/index.html#usage-2):

```
var session = require('express-session');
var Keycloak = require('keycloak-connect');

var memoryStore = new session.MemoryStore();
var keycloak = new Keycloak({ store: memoryStore });
```

However, after a user log in/ log out flow, `connect.sid` [cookie](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session#name) originating from [express-session](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session) is still stored inside browser. It causes unexpected issues if another user logs in via the same browser afterwards.

How to clear `connect.sid` express-session cookie correctly?

Overriding [adapter's session store code](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-nodejs-connect/blob/master/stores/session-store.js) by adding `response.clearCookie('connect.sid', { path: '/' });` to `unstore` function helped. However, it seems too complicated:

```
    var SessionStore = require('keycloak-connect/stores/session-store');

    let store = (grant) => {
        return (request, response) => {
          request.session[SessionStore.TOKEN_KEY] = grant.__raw;
        };
    };

    let unstore = (request, response) => {
        delete request.session[SessionStore.TOKEN_KEY];
        response.clearCookie('connect.sid', { path: '/' });
    };

    SessionStore.prototype.wrap = (grant) => {
        if (grant) {
          grant.store = store(grant);
          grant.unstore = unstore;
        }
    };
```

Does some keycloak adapter or express-session configuration achieve the goal better?

Comment: What kind of problems do you get? The fact that the cookie is still stored in the browser after /logoff should not be a big deal. If the Server has deleted the session for that cookie. On a next request, Keycloak should send your new user to a login page and then refesh the cookie.

Comment: Are you using the front-end keycloak.js as well? or the whole authentication/authorization is done by the back-end only?

Comment: the whole authentication/authorization is done by the back-end only, ui relies on backend

Comment: The problem is that cookie `'connect.sid'` is not deleted after logout

Comment: what happens when a request comes in with an old cookie? The logic responsible for checking in against the session should flag it as a wrong cookie and a new login process should start.

Comment: Regarding the delete cookie: There's no effective way to do that. The browser chooses when to delete it, you can  "suggest it" by setting the expiration information. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27978868/destroy-cookie-nodejs

Comment: Also, connect.sid could be a cookie session store. I don't remember seeing this cookie in my work with keycloak. A quick search points towards express-passport

Answer (score 0):

Your thinking is correct, I'm not sure overriding Keycloak's `unstore` method is the best way to go about it though (might mess things up if you upgrade Keycloak, or if you want to use `unstoreGrant` to remove just the grant, but keep the rest of the session).

A better approach would be to create a new middleware that triggers on your logout route:

```
app.use('/logout', (req, res, next) => {
  req.session.destroy();
  res.clearCookie('connect.sid', { path: '/' });
  res.redirect(keycloak.logoutUrl()); // optional
});
```