# Nextjs- api routes , How to remove a cookie from header?

Tags: node.js, express, cookies, next.js

I have two API routes which I want to set two cookies in `/api/login.js` and remove them in `/api/logout.js`.

so this is my login API:

```
import { serialize } from 'cookie';

export default async (req, res) => {
  res.setHeader('Set-Cookie', [
    serialize('mytoken1', 'mytoken1Value', {
      path: '/',
    }),
    serialize('mytoken2', 'mytoken2Value', {
      path: '/',
    }),
  ]);

  res.writeHead(302, { Location: '/' });
  res.end();
}
```

and this is my logout API:

```
export default async (req, res) => {
  res.removeHeader('Set-Cookie')

  res.writeHead(302, { Location: '/api/login' });
  res.end();
}
```

but the logout doesn't remove the cookies so I still can see them in **_app.js** ---console.log(req.headers.cookie)--- when I reload the page. Do you know how to remove a cookie in this situation?

Comment: to clear a cookie you set it again with a date in the past, not simply remove the header

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Destroy cookie NodeJs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27978868/destroy-cookie-nodejs)

Comment: @LawrenceCherone I've tried it not working  unfortunately

Comment: the second link you sent is not working. it keeps saying : 

TypeError: cookie__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3___default.a.set is not a function

Answer (score 14, accepted):

So, after challenging too much with every solution I ended up with this and it works fine:

**(I had multiple cookies and I had to use nodejs methods cause I was coding in nextjs API routes without any middleware)**

```
export default async (req, res) => {
  /* remove cookies from request header */
  res.setHeader('Set-Cookie', [
    serialize('mytoken1', '', {
      maxAge: -1,
      path: '/',
    }),
    serialize('mytoken2', '', {
      maxAge: -1,
      path: '/',
    }),
  ]);

  res.writeHead(302, { Location: '/api/login' });
  res.end();
}
```

The point was the maxAge which should be -1 to make it expire. I tried it with Date.now(). And when you have multiple cookies you have to end the response after manipulating both of them.

Answer (score 11):

You can do it this way:

```
res.setHeader('Set-Cookie', 'mytoken1=deleted; path=/; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT');
res.setHeader('Set-Cookie', 'mytoken2=deleted; path=/; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT');
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5285982/1376440)

UPD

```
src/pages/api/auth/signout.ts

import { NextApiHandler } from 'next';
import { NotFoundError } from 'errors/not-found-error';
import { errorHandler } from 'middlewares/error-handler';

const routeHandler: NextApiHandler = (req, res) => {
  if (req.method === 'POST') {
    res.setHeader('Set-Cookie', 'jwt=deleted; path=/; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT');
    res.send({});
  } else {
    throw new NotFoundError();
  }
};

export default errorHandler(routeHandler);
```

Comment: Does not work this way! It says res.setHeader is not defined

Comment: Here my code and it works:
file:```src/pages/api/auth/signout.ts```
```import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse, NextApiHandler } from 'next';
import { NotFoundError } from 'errors/not-found-error';

const routeHandler: NextApiHandler = (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) => {
  if (req.method === 'POST') {
    res.setHeader('Set-Cookie', 'jwt=deleted; path=/; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT');
    res.send({});
  } else {
    throw new NotFoundError();
  }
};

export default routeHandler;```

Comment: could you please edit your answer and add this code to it so that it could be more readable? Thanks

Comment: I added this snippet to my answer

Answer (score 8):

inside next.js api route you can try :

```
export default async(req, res) => {
    res.setHeader(
        "Set-Cookie", [
        `access=deleted; Max-Age=0; path=/`,
        `refresh=deleted; Max-Age=0; path=/`]
        );

    return res.status(200).json({
        success: 'Successfully logged out'
    });
}
```

or by use cookie.serialize from cookie npm package  you can try :

```
import cookie from 'cookie';
export default async(req, res) => {
    res.setHeader('Set-Cookie', [
        cookie.serialize(
            'access', '', {
                expires: new Date(0),
                path: '/'
            }
        ),
        cookie.serialize(
            'refresh', '', {
                expires: new Date(0),
                path: '/'
            }
        )
    ]);

   return res.status(200).json({
       success: 'Successfully logged out'
   });


}
```

and inside server side props page you can use

```
export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
    context.res.setHeader(
        "Set-Cookie", [
        `access=deleted; Max-Age=0; path=/`,
        `refresh=deleted; Max-Age=0; path=/`]
        );
    return { props: { } }
}
```

i hope this helpful for you .

Answer (score 0):

You can delete the cookies in middleware too.

```
if (request.cookies.has("token")) {
  const response = NextResponse.next();
  response.cookies.delete("token");
  return response;
}
```