# How to delete cookie in nextjs middleware

Tags: next.js

Unable to delete cookie in nextjs middleware. Tried the following:

```
import type { NextFetchEvent, NextRequest } from "next/server";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
export function middleware(req: NextRequest, ev: NextFetchEvent) {
  const cookie = req.cookies.get('access_token')?.value;
  const headers: any = req.headers;
  const response = NextResponse.next();

  console.log('req.headers ', headers.get('logout'))
  if (headers.get('logout')) {
    console.log(cookie);
    response.cookies.delete('access_token');
    console.log(req.cookies.get('access_token')?.value); // still logs the cookie
  }

  return response;
}
```

Comment: @AdamJenkins I tried deleting it from both req and res but it doesn't work

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Nextjs- api routes , How to remove a cookie from header?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62101821/nextjs-api-routes-how-to-remove-a-cookie-from-header)

Answer (score -1):

If you use `cookies-next` library it has `deleteCookie`

```
 import { getCookie,deleteCookie } from "cookies-next";

// its type
export declare const deleteCookie: (key: string, options?: OptionsType) => void;
```

[how to you use cookies-next](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75895092/how-to-set-a-cookie-in-client-side-in-nextjs-13/75895152#75895152)

Answer (score -1):

if someone encountered this problem you can use

response.cookies.delete('access_token')