# How delete cookies in node js

Tags: node.js, express, cookies

Hello guys I have this cookie I want to know how I can delete it I'm tired of trying and it didn't work, I tried it with res.clearCookie ()

```
res.cookie('teste', username, {maxAge: 10000 });
```

Somebody help me? Please

Answer (score 0):

Welcome Jessica, if I am not wrong , I don't think there is a way to delete cookies in nodejs except by setting up the expiration date. This below code should do the job, because you are setting the expiration date to now

```
cookies.set('teste', {expires: Date.now()});
```

Comment: I am wrong, there are many answer and alternative here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27978868/destroy-cookie-nodejs

Comment: i tried res.clearCookie () but it doesn't work, my god ...

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve with:

```
res.clearCookie()
```

actually the problem is that I was creating the cookie again on the client side