# res.clearCookie - Delete a JWT token

Tags: node.js, typescript, jwt

I'm trying to set-up a route that delete cookie containing a JWT on the client's browser.

To perform that, I'm using the res.ClearCookie function

```
    public async logOut (req: Request, res: Response) {

        res.clearCookie('auth-token', {httpOnly: true, path:'/', domain: 'localhost'});

        console.log('cookie deleted')

    }
```

I have seen that clearCookie function has to contain the same object that I passed during it creation, so here is the way I created it

```
const accessToken: string = jwt.sign({id: existingUser.id}, process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET || 'tokensecret' )

return res.cookie('auth-token', accessToken, {httpOnly: true, path:'/', domain: 'localhost'}).json(mainWallet[0].id)
```

This way, the cookie isn't deleted when I try to logout.

Do you have an idea to fix that ?

Thanks,

Paul

Comment: Maybe this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27978868/destroy-cookie-nodejs#comment115315388_27982797 helps you

Comment: hey @Anatoly, thanks you for your response. Sadly, none of the solutions suggested in the other thread work in my case...

Answer (score 0):

I have followed a new tutorial that say to setup the log-out route this way.  this time it's works

```
res.status(202).clearCookie('auth-token').send('cookie cleared')
```

Answer (score 0):

use these set of codes to construct your Api. this is the cleanest and shortest i have found for logout

```
export const logout = async (req, res, next) => {
  res.clearCookie("jwt");
  res.redirect("/");
};
```

This only clear the tokens stored in the cookie