# Unable to clearCookie for deployed application onto Render.com

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, jwt, render.com

I've hosted my MERN application to Render.com and I'm seeing the issue of not being able to clear the cookie from my browser.

However, i'm able to remove the cookie from Postman and Localhost from both chrome and edge

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

frontend

```
    logout: builder.mutation({
      query: (data) => ({
        url: `${base_url}/auth/logout`,
        method: 'POST',
        body: data,
        credentials: 'include',
        withCredentials: true
      })
```

logout controller

```
const logoutUser = async (req, res) => {
  res.clearCookie('token', {}, {sameSite:'none', secure:true}).status(200).json({message: 'Logged out'})
}
```

server.js

```
const express = require('express')
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
require('dotenv').config()

//express app
const app = express()
app.set("trust proxy", 1);
//middleweare to read body, parse it and place results in req.bdoy
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}))       // for application/x-www-form-urlencoded

//set requesst size to 50mb
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: "50mb" }))

const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
app.use(cookieParser());

//middleware to enable requests between multiple browsers 
const cors = require('cors')
app.use(cors({origin: ['http://localhost:5173', 'https://bpun1p-chat-app.onrender.com'], credentials: true}))


//connect to mongodb
mongoose.connect(process.env.DB_URI, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true })

const server = app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Listening at: http://localhost:${PORT}`))
```

Comment: These links might help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/27981898/13358783 - https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.download