# Best way to delete cookie, server-side

Tags: node.js, cookies, express

I am working with Node.js and want to delete all cookies for the browser, for my domain. What would be the best way to do this? Just set them to expire, or is there another trick?

Comment: It would help if you explained why you want to do this.  If it's because you put some data in the cookie that you didn't want the user to have, then there's not much you can do because there's nothing stopping the user from making a copy of the cookie, for example.

Comment: I am working with a legacy server, and a new Node.js server. The session is being set by the Node.js server, and the legacy server is reading the browser's cookies to confirm authenticity. 

On logout, I want to delete the user's cookies, so on either server we see absence of cookies = logged out.

Comment: So, I want to delete the cookies to log the user out.

Comment: How would the legacy server handle an empty cookie?  I don't think you can delete a cookie, but you could overwrite it.  Did you see this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5285940/correct-way-to-delete-cookies-server-side?rq=1

Comment: On any request that required authentication, the legacy server would make sure that there was a cookie, otherwise the request would be considered unathenticated.

I did checkout that post, but that is 4 years old and wanted to see if there was a better way now.

Answer (score 11):

This is quite late, but there is a clearCookie() method on the Express response object. No need to use tricks, or artificially expire the cookie. Documentation here: https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.clearCookie

Comment: Spoiler:

*res.clearCookie('name');*

This appears to work before throwing an exception as well. :) Thanks!