# Delete cookies from http header?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cookies, http-headers

I am using a web service with simple header authentication

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge {
    NSString *userName = [_usernameTextField.text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];;
    NSString *passWord  = [_passwordTextfield.text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
    if ([challenge previousFailureCount] == 0) {
        //Creating new credintial
        NSURLCredential *newCredential = [NSURLCredential credentialWithUser:userName
                                                                    password:passWord
                                                                 persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistenceForSession];
        [[challenge sender] useCredential:newCredential forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
    }
    else {
        CommonCode*objCommon=[[CommonCode alloc]init];
        [_activityIndicator stopAnimating];
        [objCommon showAlert:@"Invalid Password, or no user found with this Email Address"];
    }
}
```

On the logout I am clearing the cokies with

```
- (void)resetCredintialCache {
    NSDictionary *credentialsDict = [[NSURLCredentialStorage sharedCredentialStorage] allCredentials];
    if ([credentialsDict count] > 0) {
        // the credentialsDict has NSURLProtectionSpace objs as keys and dicts of userName => NSURLCredential
        NSEnumerator *protectionSpaceEnumerator = [credentialsDict keyEnumerator];
        id urlProtectionSpace;
        // iterate over all NSURLProtectionSpaces
        while (urlProtectionSpace = [protectionSpaceEnumerator nextObject]) {
            NSEnumerator *userNameEnumerator = [credentialsDict[urlProtectionSpace] keyEnumerator];
            id userName;
            // iterate over all usernames for this protectionspace, which are the keys for the actual NSURLCredentials
            while (userName = [userNameEnumerator nextObject]) {
                NSURLCredential *cred = credentialsDict[urlProtectionSpace][userName];
                [[NSURLCredentialStorage sharedCredentialStorage] removeCredential:cred forProtectionSpace:urlProtectionSpace];
            }
        }
        NSURLCache *sharedCache = [NSURLCache sharedURLCache];
        [sharedCache removeAllCachedResponses];
        NSHTTPCookieStorage *cookieStorage = [NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage];

        NSArray *cookies = [cookieStorage cookies];
        for (NSHTTPCookie *cookie in cookies) {

            [cookieStorage deleteCookie:cookie];
        }
    }
}
```

But after logout if I enter the wrong password I am logged in as theprevious user. How do I delete the cookies from the header of the HTTP request?

Comment: Have you gone through this post... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5285940/correct-way-to-delete-cookies-server-side

Comment: how to use this one?

Comment: Which one , you need to clarify.

Comment: sorry  . stackoverflow.com/questions/5285940   in this link

Comment: Set-Cookie: token=deleted; path=/; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT

Answer (score 1):

NSURLRequest has a cachePolicy property, which specifies the caching behaviour of the request.

Set the following cache policy **NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData** when making the request like the example bellow will load the data from the url and not from the cache.

```
NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData timeoutInterval:10];
```

> NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData
>
> Specifies that the data for the URL load should be loaded from the
>   originating source. No existing cache data should be used to satisfy a
>   URL load request.

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLRequest_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/NSURLRequestCachePolicy