# Create JWT Blacklist in Spring Cloud Gateway

Tags: spring-oauth2, jwt, spring-cloud-gateway, blacklist

I integrated spring cloud gateway with oauth2 login. After logout in scg, the user still can access resource server because the user has valid token. I need to invalidate this valid token in some way. there is blacklist solution as my researches (https://stackoverflow.com/a/53994938/5079581) and i will implement this.

by creating filter, i take jwt in step of "/logout" and put it to blacklist.

```
public class ExampleWebFilter implements WebFilter {

    @Override
    public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange serverWebExchange, WebFilterChain webFilterChain) {
        ServerHttpRequest request = serverWebExchange.getRequest();
        String uri = request.getPath().pathWithinApplication().value();
        HttpHeaders headers = request.getHeaders();
        if(uri.equals("/logout")) {
            List<String> auth = headers.get("Authorization");
        }

        return webFilterChain.filter(serverWebExchange);
    }

}
```

auth list always returns null. i think that my filter works before token relay filter. how can i access the jwt at gateway? is there any code sample or demo for this? Thanks.

Comment: Could you please post your answer if you have already solved. I am having the same problem and trying to fix it

Answer (score 0):

In spring cloud gateway + security oauth2 integration, JWTs are stored in gateway as session. At first, i thought there was an error about saving JWT as session, as it becomes stateful. But, when you logged out, this session is removed and there is no JWT anymore, so **there is no need to create blacklist**. this way of working is a clever solution.

So, what was my problem? **I had 2 seperate servers (gateway, oauth2 server)**. two sessions are created as a result of the operation. **SESSION for gateway, JSESSION for oauth2 server.** when you logged out at gateway, **only SESSION is removed, but JSESSION is still alive.** because of that, the gateway goes oauth server(and still signed in oauth2 server) and get new JWT.

To log out completely in system, **you also need to logged out from ouath2 server** at the same time.