# destroy session method on rails API for react front end

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, devise, token

I'm building the token authentication for the rails side of the project project. which uses devise and JWT gems. I need to write a method(in session controller) to destroy the user session. Does anyone know how to go about doing this? in the front end the token is held in sessions when the user is logged in.

```
class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  # protect_from_forgery with: :null_session, if: ->{request.format.json?}
  # skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token


      def create
        user = User.find_by_email(params[:email])
    
        if user && user.valid_password?(params[:password])
          @current_user = user
        else
          render json: { errors: { 'email or password' => ['is invalid'] } }, status: :unprocessable_entity
        end
      end
    
      def destroy
        # stuck here
      end
    
    end
```

here's the application controller too

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :null_session
  respond_to :json
  before_action :underscore_params!
  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?
  before_action :authenticate_user
  
  private

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:username])
  end

  def authenticate_user
    if request.headers['Authorization'].present?
      authenticate_or_request_with_http_token do |token|
        begin
          jwt_payload = JWT.decode(token, Rails.application.secrets.secret_key_base).first

          @current_user_id = jwt_payload['id']
        rescue JWT::ExpiredSignature, JWT::VerificationError, JWT::DecodeError
          head :unauthorized
        end
      end
    end
  end

  def underscore_params!
    params.deep_transform_keys!(&:underscore)
  end

  def authenticate_user!(options = {})
    head :unauthorized unless signed_in?
  end

  def current_user
    @current_user ||= super || User.find(@current_user_id)
  end

  def signed_in?
    @current_user_id.present?
  end

end
```

Comment: Have a read on that one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37962259/1202324

Comment: Since you are using Devise, you might consider [devise-jwt](https://github.com/waiting-for-dev/devise-jwt). In addition to JWT authentication, it provides pluggable strategies for managing token revocation, with three common strategies out of the box.