# What is the proper way to implementing the revoke(Blacklist) token URL in FastAPI, Django, Flask?

Tags: python, django, model-view-controller, fastapi, api-design

I'm implementing the JWT in FastAPI, Which is proper way to revoke the access and refresh tokens for the Logout?

1. Single Logout URL to revoke the access and refresh
2. Individual revoke URL?

Thanks in advance

Comment: what about jwt expiry?

Comment: Revoke tokens only for Logout

Comment: If the session is maintaining in JWT, in logout interface (UI), just clear the token from the client side will be enough. No need of URL here.

Comment: Please have a look at [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37959945/how-to-destroy-jwt-tokens-on-logout) and [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21978658/invalidating-json-web-tokens).

Answer (score 1):

JWT is designed to be stateless, which means when a JWT is created, you can not expire it on the server side. You'll just have to wait for it to expire, or you can tell client to delete it.

If you still insist on deleting a JWT on the server side, you'll need some kind of blacklist as described in [this post](https://medium.com/devgorilla/how-to-log-out-when-using-jwt-a8c7823e8a6)

You can also take a look at [blacklist functionality](https://django-rest-framework-simplejwt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/blacklist_app.html) in Django `rest_framework_simplejwt`,

Comment: I agree. My question is for blacklist(Revoke) should I use Single URL to blacklist the both token passing token in parms (or) Individual URL for access_token and refresh_roken

Comment: A single URL to blacklist with refresh_token as parameter should be sufficient. This is how `rest_framework_simplejwt`  implements. Of course, you need a short-lived access-token, for example, 5 mins.