# JWT token is not destroyed after calling destroy method

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, redis, jwt

I am using `jwt-redis` library to generate and destroy JWT tokens.

I need to destroy the JWT token from server side when user logs out so that token is not misused.
Below is the code I am using to generate and destroy token:

```
const redis = require("redis");
const JWTR = require("jwt-redis").default;
const generateJWTToken = async (data) => {
  const redisClient = redis.createClient();
  await redisClient.connect();
  const jwtr = new JWTR(redisClient);

  const token = await jwtr.sign(data, process.env.JWT_KEY);
  return token;
};

const verifyJWTToken = async (token) => {
  const redisClient = redis.createClient();
  await redisClient.connect();
  const jwtr = new JWTR(redisClient);

  const data = await jwtr.verify(token, process.env.JWT_KEY);
  return data;
};

const destroyJWTToken = async (token) => {
  const redisClient = redis.createClient();
  await redisClient.connect();
  const jwtr = new JWTR(redisClient);
  await jwtr.destroy(token, process.env.JWT_KEY);
};
```

Even after destroying the token when I call `verifyJWTToken` method, it returns the data which were signed with the token.

After destroying the token, it should not return signed data.

What am I doing wrong here?

Any new techniques to destroy JWT token from node server is also appreciated!

Comment: This question already has answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37962259/18283121)

Comment: Both questions are different. Please first read the requirements of both questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jwtr.destroy returns a promise, so try

```
await jwtr.destroy(token.jti, process.env.JWT_KEY);
```

Comment: I tried with await too. but it doesn't work

Comment: why you are creating new Client inside destroyJwtToken ? try initiating only once in the file..

Comment: As you suggested, I tried with using single redis client, still it is not working

Comment: is it throwing any error ?

Comment: it seems like you have to pass jti in destroy function ? refer.. https://github.com/Natashkinsasha/jwt-redis-v2

Comment: No, it is not throwing any error. One more thing is that I have logged response of jwtr.destroy which is `false`

Comment: try passing as ...    eg:   await jwtr.destroy(token.jti, process.env.JWT_KEY);

Comment: token.jti is not working

Comment: but before destroying the token, first I need to decode data from token and take the jti from decoded data to get the exact jti for each token

Comment: is it working now ?

Answer (score 0):

Just use the following code snip for destroying tokens when you are using jwt-redis. because jwt-redis npm documentation itself said that you can destroy tokens only using jti. please refer https://www.npmjs.com/package/jwt-redis cerate jti & destory token method.

```
await jwtr.destroy(token.jti);
```