# Issues on destroy jwt token cookie from express

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, jwt, express-jwt

```js
//creation of token 
res.cookie('jwt', token, { httpOnly: true, maxAge : 60 * 60 * 24});
// the logout and where i want to destroy it
 exports.logout = (req, res) => {
    res.cookie('jwt', "token", {httpOnly:true,maxAge:1000})
    // res.clearCookie('jwt');
}
```

it can't be destroyed after the logout function

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to destroy JWT Tokens on logout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37959945/how-to-destroy-jwt-tokens-on-logout)

Answer (score 0):

You need to set an expiry date in the past, similar to this. Browsers will then discard the cookie and stop sending it. If applicable use the same cookie domain and path that you used when creating the cookie.

```js
res.cookie('jwt', "", {
    httpOnly: true, 
    expires: new Date(Date.now() - 86400),
})
```

Answer (score 0):

i tried this by changing the value and the expiration time :

```js
res.clearCookie('jwt', {httpOnly:true,maxAge:1, value: "token"})
```