# How would changing Django's cookie domain settings cause sporadic CSRF failures?

Tags: python, django, cookies, csrf

In my Django project, until recently I had left the settings `SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN` and `CSRF_COOKIE_DOMAIN` unset. Recently I changed them to `.mydomain.com` and since then I have been seeing sporadic CSRF failures on AJAX requests for certain users. The failure manifests as a 403 with `CSRF token missing or incorrect.` appearing in the logs.

Asking users to clear cookies seems to resolve the issue, but I'm wondering how the settings change could have caused this and why it only seems to be happening for some users and not others.

Wondering if there is a way to resolve these issues without asking my users to clear cookies.

Comment: I don't know the answer, but the documentation does [suggest](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN) that this can cause problems: "Be cautious when updating this setting on a production site. If you update this setting to enable cross-domain cookies on a site that previously used standard domain cookies, existing user cookies will be set to the old domain. This may result in them being unable to log in as long as these cookies persist."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cookie with the new `SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN` is sent as a new cookie and does not replace the old one. So the browser will send *both* to your server. AFAICT, it sends them in arbitrary order.

That means that you're *setting* a cookie for `.mydomain.com`, but *receiving* either the cookie you just set for `.mydomain.com`, or a stale cookie for `whatever.mydomain.com` was implicitly set originally (because django will only pick one, most likely the last it sees). Which one you get depends on the browser, possibly on some particulars of how the client computer stores them, and possibly even on how django reads the headers. This is why the failures are inconsistent: it randomly works for some clients and fails for others.

**Edit:** You could delete the stale cookie from the server, if you know the original cookie's properties. Probably the best way is to set a custom `Set-Cookie` header with the domain and other properties set, and expiration date in the past. You could do that e.g. from the 403 page handler.
(see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie and [Correct way to delete cookies server-side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5285940/correct-way-to-delete-cookies-server-side) )

Comment: This indeed turned out to be the issue. We resolved by adding a JS snippet into our base template that set an expired cookie with `Domain=` and that effectively invalidated the old ones.