# How ignore or delete dns caché browsers from my server?

Tags: node.js, linux, cookies, browser-cache

I made an migration website server. Now, my clients have the previous ip address cached in their browsers. They must to clean cookies & caché and its a nuisance.

I'm wondering if exist somehow to ignore or delete this caché from my server or somewhere that i can control.

Thanks!

Server Technologies: Linux, Nginx, Nodejs, React.

Answer (score 0):

you can remove cookies in node side and return an HTTP header with an empty field for `Set-Cookie`.

[here is explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5285940/correct-way-to-delete-cookies-server-side)

Comment: The problem is that the caché browser  is pointing to previusly server (I haven't permissions on that server now). The easy way is set-cookies from the previous server. But I cant do it.