# Deleting all cookies

Tags: go

I'm having a difficult time deleting all cookies using the following code. What seems to happen is that the domain is changed to append a dot in front of it. Instead of deleting all cookies, I get duplicate cookies with slightly different domains. Is there any way to completely remove all cookies no matter what their domain looks like?

Thanks for any help!

```
//DeleteCookies deletes all cookies
func DeleteCookies(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    for _, c := range r.Cookies() {
        deleted := &http.Cookie{
        Name: c.Name,
        Path: c.Path,
        //Expires:  time.Unix(0, 0),
        MaxAge:   -10,
        HttpOnly: c.HttpOnly,
        Domain:   c.Domain,
        Secure:   c.Secure,
        Value:    "",
        }
        http.SetCookie(w, deleted)
    }
}
```

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5285940/correct-way-to-delete-cookies-server-side

Comment: @MuffinTop This is wrong. Cookies are identified by the tripple (Domain,Name,Path) so you must not modify the path when deleting the cookie.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you try to do doesn't work well as cookies do not work that way.

The easy things first:
HttpOnly, Domain and Secure: These values are **not** transmitted in a HTTP client request, these fields of `c` will always be empty. The client *uses* these fields to determine whether to send a (Name,Value)-pair in the `Cookie` header or not but doesn't send these values.

For HttpOnly, Secure (and SameSite) this does not matter as these (and MaxAge and Expires) do **not** contribute to the *cookie* *identity*.

*Cookie* *identity* is based on the tripple (Domain,Path,Name) as sent in a `SetCookie` header. Often Domain and Path are implicit but they do have defined values on the client.

Now to delete a cookie with identity (Domain-X, Path-X, Name-X) you must send a cookie with the same identity (Domain-X, Path-X, Name-X) and MaxAge=-1. But as explained above the cookie you *receive* doesn't contain Domain and Path.

There are two ways out:

1. You must know whether your cookies are domain or host cookies and which path they were set for and use that information to delete them. (I would recommend this.)
2. Delete all *possible* cookies. Upon a request to path `/foo/bar/wuz` the cookies from the client might stem from path `/`, `/foo` or  `/foo/bar` (if I remember correctly; test and look it up in RFC 6265). So delete the cookie with name "Name-X" for all these paths. Do the same for the Domain attribute which unfortunately is more complicated. Delete the host cookie (Domain=="") and delete the domain cookies (Domain!=""). Make sure to get the right domain name (the effective TLD plus one).

As you see 2 is pretty complicated. But that is how cookies are designed: The server is expected to *know* what cookies the servers sets i.e. the server is expected to know the cookie identity (Domain,Path,Name) of all its cookies. The responsibility of the client is to send back the appropriate (Name,Value) pair for a certain request only. If the server wishes to delete a cookie it just sets MaxAge of that cookie to -1. Note that "that cookie" is something the server is expected to know and not infer from a client request.