# Axios error handling when executing a request on the server side using Next.js 13

Tags: javascript, next.js, axios, react-server-components

I just recently started working with next.js 13 and using the app directory. I ran into a problem using axios and interceptors.

Description:
I can't find information on how to handle an error, for example 401 status if the request is executed on the server. I need to catch the 401 status and make a user logout. There is little information on this question on the Internet, maybe someone has also encountered this.

Problem:
Due to the fact that the request is being executed on the server, I can't delete the cookie and make a redirect. The same problem with the 404 status, it is necessary to catch and redirect the user to `/page-not-found`.

My code:

Axios Instance and Interceptors

```
import axios from "axios";
import { notFound } from "next/navigation";
import { TokenStorageService } from "@/services/TokenStorageService";

const baseUrl = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_ROOT_URL;

const isClient = typeof window !== "undefined";

const instance = axios.create({
  baseURL: baseUrl,
  headers: {
    "Content-type": "application/json",
  },
});

instance.interceptors.request.use(
  async (config) => {
    const token = await TokenStorageService.getToken();

    if (token) {
      config.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${token}`;
    }

    return config;
  },
  (error) => Promise.reject(error),
);

instance.interceptors.response.use(
  (config) => config,
  async (error) => {
    if (axios.isAxiosError(error)) {
      const { response } = error;

      if (response && response.status === 401) {
        if (isClient) {
          TokenStorageService.removeToken();
          window.location.href = "/auth";
        }
      }

      if (response && response.status === 404) {
        notFound();
      }
    }

    return Promise.reject(error);
  },
);

export default instance;
```

Token Storage Service:

```
import Cookies from "js-cookie";

export const TOKEN_KEY = "token";
const isServer = typeof window === "undefined";

export const TokenStorageService = {
  setToken(token: string) {
    Cookies.set(TOKEN_KEY, token);
  },

  async getToken() {
    return isServer
      ? (await import("next/headers")).cookies().get(TOKEN_KEY)?.value
      : Cookies.get(TOKEN_KEY);
  },

  removeToken() {
    Cookies.remove(TOKEN_KEY);
  },
};
```

I will be glad of any help. If possible, please give examples. Thanks

Comment: your axios code is using `window` so this will not work server side so there is more to fix here. I have never tried to use axios interceptor server side but an alternativ would be to create aa utility file where you would handle this. For the Cookie, you could send the `Set-Cookie` as in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5285940/correct-way-to-delete-cookies-server-side

Comment: @grekier, There is a best practice for error handling if axios interceptor in Next.js isn't the best idea?

Comment: interceptor might work fine in Nextjs but you cannot use `window` since it will run server side, it will be undefined